# Rails Distinct with Condition

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have four table in data  which have repeated status but with different created_at (assuming it is on an associated model named "test")

Sample:

```
column 1: status_type : "test", created_at: "2019-08-14"

column 2: status_type : "test", created_at: "2020-20-14"

column 3: status_type : "integer", created_at: "2021-20-15"

column 4: status_type : "integer", created_at: "2022-22"15"
```

I want to get two data which is test and integer but i need the one who is the most updated or who is more recent based on their created_at. How to query this? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following

```
Class.where(status_type: ['test', 'integer']).order('created_at').select('DISTINCT ON (status_type) *')
```

Comment: Thanks but what if the created_at exists on association? The class which has the status_type belongs_to this second class which has_many of this aforementioned class which has status_type

Comment: Assuming tests is the association you can do `record.tests.order("created_at").last`

Comment: but i don't want the where? i want to get all the datas with using only one query

Comment: You mean for both `test` and `integer`?

Comment: Yes i want one query where i get both of them because what if i have another status_type, i just want a distinct status_type and by its recent associated created_at

Comment: Class.includes(:test).order(“tests.created_at desc”).distinct("DISTINCT ON (status_name) *") so it doesn;t work?

Comment: Actually, you are right you can do that, if you order them first and then apply the `DISTINCT` it will work.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the productive comment. I actually did it based on your hint lool